# How to resolve errors of acm template

Tags: templates, acm, acmart, relsize

I download acm journals template from following link, but running it gives error http://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions
First it gives following error 
`Undefined control sequence. \toprule
Undefined control sequence. \bottomrule`

which i resolved by adding following packages

`\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Then did not showed pdf while log is following

`relsize.sty Warning Failed to get list of font sizes.
comment.cut badbox Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
name{Hfootnote.3} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`

And in the messages

`Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "sample-manuscript".tex
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following rea
son: The txsya source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page,
if you need help.
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK font txsya could not be created. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Name/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
Process exited with error(s)`

**UPDATED** After uninstalling and then reinstalling. Above error is resolved, but following error came.
`pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts. T
Failed to get list of font sizes.`

Note that i googled to resolve above error and added following packages
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}`

But it did not help to resolve error

Comment: There are quite a few files in the zip file from ACM. Could you tell us exactly what you have done, after unzipping (i.e. what did you try to compile, and with what commands)?

Comment: I just run sample-manuscript.tex

Comment: @IanThompson i did not added any thing, just run it and error comes and then i google it added above two packages and then again above errors come

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The current version of MikTeX contains the current `acmart`.  You might be better off installing `acmart` using MikTeX package manager.
2. Anyway looks like you do not have `txfonts` package installed.  This is the reason of your error message,

Comment: They are already installed

Comment: you may try reinstalling: looks like a broken system...

Comment: The rtxr source file could not be found. How can i resolve this

Comment: I think you can reinstall txfonts - or maybe the whole system - using MikTeX package manager

Comment: Thanks it resolved above error, but now it gives `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.`

Comment: I added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} these packages

Comment: `lmodern` means that you use latin modern fonts instead of libertine and txfonts, as ACM wants.  Please install the proper fonts

Comment: i did not get your point! which fonts should i need to install......I have already installed `lmodern`

Comment: acm does not use lmodern.  it uses libertine and txfonts

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now. As you suggested i added `\usepackage{txfonts} \usepackage{libertine} \usepackage{lmodern}`. However it works without `\usepackage{libertine}` package. It needed `\usepackage{txfonts} \usepackage{lmodern}`, without these two packages it gives following error `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts`.

Comment: Kindly add you suggestions that you gave in comment section, as part of your answer, I am accepting this.